# FileHelpers interprets event handlers as fields

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I have a class that I have consumed from a web service that I am trying to export to csv using the `FileHelpers` library.  However the class has a `PropertyChangedEventHandler` which the engine is reading as a field so I'm getting the following exception

> {"The field: 'PropertyChanged' of type: PropertyChangedEventHandler is
>   a non system type, so this field need a CustomConverter (see the docs
>   for more info)."}

Ive tried adding the `FieldIgnored` attribute but then I get the compiler error saying the attribute is only valid on field declarations

Is there any way to get the engine to ignore the event handler?  Or am I going to have to convert the results of the web service call into a completely new (all be it identical class)?

Any ideas

Answer (score 1):

Your problem occurs because of a combination of the way C# auto-implements an `event`, and the failure of the library you're using to specifically detect this scenario and offer a more useful error message.

In particular, when you declare this:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

What you really get in your class is something like this:

```
private PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
{
    add { PropertyChanged += value; }
    remove { PropertyChanged -= value; }
}
```

The exact implementation of the `add` and `remove` methods has changed over the years. Indeed, the above is just for the example…the compiler's never actually implemented an event exactly like that. The important thing is that you get *both* an event and a field, with the same name. The library is finding the field and complaining about it.

You should be able to work around the issue by just implementing the event explicitly yourself. For example:

```
[FieldIgnored]
private PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChangedField;

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
{
    add { PropertyChanged += value; }
    remove { PropertyChanged -= value; }
}
```

This will work fine as long as you don't need for the `add` and `remove` methods to be thread-safe. However, note that the C# compiler does implement event `add` and `remove` methods as thread-safe; if you want to follow the C# compiler's pattern, you'll want something like this:

```
[FieldIgnored]
private PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChangedField;

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
{
    add
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler eventHandler = this.PropertyChangedField;
        PropertyChangedEventHandler comparand;
        do
        {
            comparand = eventHandler;
            eventHandler = Interlocked.CompareExchange<PropertyChangedEventHandler>(
                ref this.PropertyChangedField,
                (PropertyChangedEventHandler) Delegate.Combine(
                    (Delegate) comparand, (Delegate) value),
                comparand);
        } while (eventHandler != comparand);
    }

    remove
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler eventHandler = this.PropertyChangedField;
        PropertyChangedEventHandler comparand;
        do
        {
            comparand = eventHandler;
            eventHandler = Interlocked.CompareExchange<PropertyChangedEventHandler>(
                ref this.PropertyChangedField,
                (PropertyChangedEventHandler) Delegate.Remove(
                    (Delegate) comparand, (Delegate) value),
                comparand);
        } while (eventHandler != comparand);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, however the event is already implement in the web service class in the auto-generated code which I don't want to touch.  I am able to add the attributes to the fields by using metadata on a partial class that I can edit. But I cant reimplement the event as you have suggested.  How do I do this when the event is in auto-generated code?

Comment: There's no mention of auto-generated or partial classes in your original question. And frankly, there's not enough context in your question to understand why and how you are using this web service class with the FileHelpers library. But given the information provided so far, it sounds like your only practical option is to use an adapter class; i.e. don't give the web service class to the FileHelpers library, but instead declare a new class used specifically for the file I/O aspect, which contains or is initialized from the web service instance.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I wrote the original question in a bit of rush.  You have pretty much confirmed what I suspected though so thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

A FileHelpers class is just a way of defining the specification of a flat file using a limited C# syntax as the definition language. As such, a FileHelpers class is an unusual type and you should not try to use it in any other way.

> Or am I going to have to convert the results of the web service call
>   into a completely new (all be it identical class)?

Yes! That is the recommended approach. Think of the FileHelpers class as the 'specification' of your CSV format only. That should be its only role.

If you need the records in a more 'normal' object (in your case, your web service class with the event), then map the results after importing. This can be done very easily with something like this:

```
FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine<FileHelpersOrder>(); 
var records = engine.ReadFile("FileIn.txt");

var niceOrders = records.Select(
    x => new NiceOrder() 
       { Number = x.Number,  
         Customer = x.Customer 
         // etc.
       });
```

Where `FileHelpersOrder` is your CSV specification and the `NiceOrder` class is your web service class proper OOP class with properties, methods, etc. as necessary.

(Note: this allows the CSV format to differ considerably from the target object. Imagine for instance you are importing a small subset of columns from a format with dozens. This approach allows you to keep things separate).

If you're exporting, then you need to do the opposite, *i.e.*, select a collection of `FileHelpersOrder` from a collection of `NiceOrder`.